# Folder Size Report to CSV

Tags: python, perl, bash, csv, du

I think I've looked everywhere and I'm not having much luck.  I'm trying to create a simple automated billing report. I need to create a CSV with 3 columns.  like this

```
Folder   Size   Billing Code
Folder1  300M   XXXXX
Folder2  600M   XXXXX
Folder3  200M   XXXXX
```

I can get a `du -sh` and use `awk` to arrange it how I want and I get most of what I'm attempting to do.  however I don't know how to create a header before each column.  I've looked for methods in bash, perl, and python and having limited success. If I could just figure out how to make the column header labels I think i'd be fine from there.

Answer (score 4):

Try the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv) in Python. Specifically, you'll want the writeheader() method, it's pretty straightforward.

Alternately, if you're already doing this in a shell script, why not just echo the header line to the file first, then making sure that the subsequent commands use the append operator ( >> )?

Answer (score 3):

What about adding the names after you render the values?

```
$ sed 1i"This is the first line" - < /proc/loadavg
This is the first line
3.14 3.48 3.58 2/533 17661
```

Comment: Hmm, the dash may be redundant, but apparently it works with it as well (:

Answer (score 1):

An approach with perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

open my $fh, '>:encoding(utf8)','your outfile.csv';

# write the first line with the column names
print $fh "Folder,Size,Billing Code\n";

# Do your folder calculations
my $dirpath = "/your/path";
my $bytes;
find(\&folders,$dirpath);
close $fh;

sub folders {
    if (-d $_) {
        $bytes = 0;
        find(\&size,$_);
        $bytes = $bytes/1_048_576; # Convert Bytes to Mega Bytes
        print $fh $_.",".$bytes."M,your_billing_code \n";
    }
}

sub size {
    if(-f $_){
        $bytes += -s _; # This is not a typo
                        # -X _ does a filesystem operation on the 
                        # last used stat structure
                        # this saves new filesystem calls and therefore performance
                        # see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html for more info
    }
}
```

This writes the CSV File without external commands like du and works on every platform.
Also check Perl's CSV Modules for more options